# NOT BETWEEN in codeigniter not working

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-3, postgresql-9.1

I want to ask why the query builder class does not included `NOT BETWEEN`. The hack i try was this 
`->where('"mytable.date" not between '." $min_date ".' AND '. "$max_date")`.

It built this query AND `"mytable"."date" "not" between "2017-5-18" AND 2017-6-7`.

How can i effectively used this with the codeigniter query builder class or active records.

I am using `postgresql` driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the code below that will work fine in my code:

```
$this->db->where("'mytable.date' NOT BETWEEN  '".$min_date."'  AND '".$max_date."'");
```

Comment: the query should be `AND "qc_data"."date" NOT BETWEEN '2017-5-18' AND '2017-6-7'`

your query is printing `AND 'qc_data.date' NOT BETWEEN '2017-5-18' AND '2017-6-7'`

Comment: then you can try with `$this->db->where( " record_status='active' AND !( mytable.date  BETWEEN '".$min_date."' AND '".$max_date."') ");`

Comment: what is the significance of record_status ?

Comment: this also did not work moreover `!` operator  i think does not work  in postgresql

Comment: `record_status` is only for the example, you can use your table column over there you can replace `!` with `NOT`  both works

Comment: works like a charm thank you so much @Jagruti i was having too much difficulty . Any reason why it did not work before the between and on internet there is not much information regarding this problem?

Comment: @fatpotato not a problem at all :) , I really don't know the reason why it did not work with because I have check on my system it'll work fine, and internet have a lot's of examples explore more you get the more information

Comment: Thank you for your response :) let me test this extensively

Answer (score 3):

I'm confused about your quotations may you try using this code below instead.

```
$this->db->where("mytable.date NOT BETWEEN '$min_date' AND '$max_date'");
```

**UPDATE**

I tried NOT BETWEEN and really doesn't work. another alternative is

```
$this->db->where('mytable.date <=', $min_date);
$this->db->where('mytable.date >=', $max_date);
```

Comment: sorry for that confusion your query is very much near to it but still it is considering not as `"not"`. i mean it is considering as a table.

Comment: your right. not between doesnt work in CI. i update my answer

Comment: i have tried this but this is querying no data actually i am using `NOT BETWEEN` for a filter in a main dates query. like i have already a set of dates but i want to exclude the dates from that set.